# Array within object returning length of 0, even though there are elements present

Tags: javascript, arrays, trie

I am trying to implement a Trie in Javascript, which is easy enough but I seem to have hit a road block with my object.

The nodes are structured as follows:

```
var node = {
    children: []
}
```

Children is an array of nodes that is mapped by a letter in a string. So the string "Test" would look like this:

```
root = {
  children: [
      't' => {
          children: [
              'e' => {
                   children: [
                       's' => {
                            children: [
                                 't' => {
                                      children: []
                                  }
                            ]
                        }
                   ]
               }
          ]
      }
  ]
};
```

So each children array should have a length of 1, but if do something like `alert(this._root.children.length);` I get zero. Any thoughts on why this is happening?

**Here is the rest of my implementation:**

```
function Trie() {
    this._root = {
        children: []
    };
}

Trie.prototype = {

    //restore constructor
    constructor: Trie,

    add: function (str){
        var curr = this._root,
            prev,
            currchar;
        // For each character in the string
        for(var i = 0, j = str.length; i < j; i++) {
            // Insert only lowercase letters for efficiency
            currchar = str.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
            prev = curr;
            curr = prev.children[currchar];
            // Traverse until we hit a non-existant node
            if(typeof(curr) == "undefined") {
                // Make a new node
                prev.children[currchar] = {
                    children: []
                };
                curr = prev.children[currchar];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling your constructor with `new Trie()`? If you aren't using `new`, that would explain why you get 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding properties to the array instance object, not elements to the array. The `length` property only includes array elements, not properties on the array instance object.

```
var a = [23, 42];
console.log(a.length); // 2
a['foo'] = 'bar';
console.log(a.length); // 2
a[2] = 1337;
console.log(a.length); // 3
```

**EDITED:**
You could instead structure the nodes like this:

```
var node = {
    children: {},
    length: function () {
        var i = 0;
        var k;

        for (k in this.children) {
            if (this.children.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                i++;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
};
```

This is inefficient, of course.  You should instead define a Node class with the length method on its prototype.  Alternatively, define an `add` method that updates the length property.

Comment: So is there any way to do this without storing another property within the object?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do.  If you just want to implement a Trie, I don't think the `length` property is really necessary.  That said, updated with code that provides a `length` method.

Comment: The length is for removing. I can't remove a node that has > 1 length because it belongs to other strings.

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend just using a helper function in your removal code that checks to see if `children` has 2 keys, since you don't actually need to know the true length.

Comment: You should declare `k` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is that you use a javasrcipt array as an associative array (as found in other languages). In javascript "associative" arrays are objects that don't have a length property. Normal arrays have numeric indices.

Irrelevant to the question but you might find [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-trie-performance-analysis/) useful.

Comment: Upvote for the link. Very useful. The problem is still going to be removing words from the Trie.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want

```
str.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(i)
```

instead of

```
str.toLowerCase().charAt(i)
```

If `str` is `"f1"`, the properties you're adding to the children array are `"f"` and `"1"` which should cause an array with property named `f` and length 0, and another child array with length `2` and property `1`.

To get only numeric properties, you should make sure your property names are valid array indices -- positive integers representable in 31 bits.

By using `charCodeAt` instead of `charCode`, you would get the property names `102` and `49` instead of `"f"` and `1`.

Comment: That would make `length` at least equal to `str.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(i)`.

Comment: @Gumbo.  Yes.  I don't know why the original design seems to want to have a length for children instead of just using an object, but I'm only trying to solve their problem.  Not revamp their entire design.

Comment: @Mike Samuel - Gumbo's point is that if, for an empty array `a`, you set `a[23] = true`, then `a.length === 24`.

Comment: @lawnsea, I understand the point.  Modern JS interpreters are perfectly capable of dealing efficiently with sparse arrays though, so I am unsure how that fact is significant.

Comment: @lawnsea, Gumbo, I think I acknowledged Gumbo's interpretation when I said "and another child array with length 2 and property 1" based on the char-wise decomposition of `str = "f1"`.  Is that not correct?  If it is, are you arguing that having an overly long array is not a wise course.  If so, I think I have already conceded that point.

Comment: @Mike Samuel - No, I'm saying - and I believe this was Gumbo's point as well - that with your solution, the value of `length` is wrong because it doesn't reflect the number of contained elements.  The array contains 1 item but reports a length much longer.  This isn't a problem for iteration, but *is* a problem if the value of length is important.  In this case, OP said in a comment on my answer that he wants to know if `children` contains more than one element.  Your technique would work for letters if you did something like `str.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(i) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0)`.

Comment: @lawnsea, Fair enough.  I don't think we disagree then.  I was trying to find the minimal change which would explain the OPer's confusion, not validating their design.